Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Aggregated and non-aggregated fields cannot be mixed in a Boolean Expression
help me, I'm have this error.
CASE
WHEN Data = MAX(Data) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
Error return: Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Aggregated and non-aggregated fields cannot be mixed in a Boolean Expression.
I want to solve the problem.
